# SQL database model - Relational or Snowflake

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-modeling

I am creating a data model and need help. I've attached dummy data in how am I expecting to receive the data as below. Its basically service amounts at different hierarchy's.

1st File has the totals and combination of all the attributes make it unique

2nd File is more detailed and similar to File 1, combination of all the attributes make it unique and Territory allocation is basically the split of the service amounts from File 1. Over the period values change, sometimes frequently with in the quarter and are updated in File 1 and based on initial allocations, Amounts from file 2 (in the database) have to be updated.

File 1

| Service | Service Category | Sub Component | Direction | YYYYQQ | Service Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T | T1 | Y | E | 202201 | 2000 |
| T | T2 | N | E | 202202 | 1000 |
| A | T1 | Y | W | 202201 | 100 |
| A | T3 | N | E | 202201 | 200 |

File 2

| Service | Service Category | Sub Component | Direction | Service Area | Service agent | Service Territory | YYYYQQ | Territory Allocation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T | T1 | Y | E | SA1 | Agent 1 | EAST001 | 202201 | 1500 |
| T | T1 | Y | E | SA1 | Agent 2 | EAST002 | 202201 | 500 |

I was thinking of a snowflake schema with a Fact at the Territory grain and Date Dim, Territory Dim with a bridge table to ServiceArea Dim and another Dimension with a combination of data from File 1 and bridge table to link ServiceArea.

I am not sure, if that's the right approach or can I build a simple relational database model. Thanks in advance

Comment: The answer will very much depend on who, or what, will be the consumer of that data model. Is it an OLTP application, SSRS with custom queries, SSAS cube, PowerBI dataset, or something else? Each of these consumers would prefer the data to be organised in different ways.

Comment: It is an OLTP application. we will have custom queries built on top of this for data comparison

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the example correctly, `File1` essentially contains aggregated values from `File2`. So, there may be little point importing both since you can always generate the former from the latter, unless for some specific reason you want to verify the consistency of data between the files.

The flat file ingestion step is usually the same for all scenarios. You create staging tables, one per file being imported, with schema identical to file's. This way you can load the data using `bulk insert` or any other bulk loading mechanism, which is as fast as it can be.

Your next step is where the differences start to appear. If you want to normalise the data, then you can add the next set of tables, some lookups (dimensions) and others facts. If, as you say, you have cross-dimensional dependencies, then snowflake looks like an obvious choice, sure. However, the question is whether it will be useful to data consumer(s). Also, if your database already has some, or all, of these lookups, I'd follow the existing model as close as possible, unless you want to rework it and are looking for a better design.

The main difficulty with answering a question like this is that you never specify the requirements the resulting schema should satisfy. It's possible that you don't know them yourself. If your goal is to have a fully normalised model, which for most people means [BCNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyce%E2%80%93Codd_normal_form), then you are free to go with the most elaborate and precise snowflake that you can think of.

On the other hand, precise models are prone to regular redesigns, exactly because they are too restrictive, inflexible and not very future-proof. So when business circumstances change and what was impossible yesterday becomes normal today, you'll have to rework not only the tables, but also the code that uses them (and possibly UI, as well).

How much leeway you should incorporate into the resulting model, and in which places? Nobody can tell you for sure, because "future is... uncertain". Subject matter experts might help, however.

*In summa summarum:* You can go either way, or even a hybrid way, and only your business users can tell you in which places you may be strict, and where it might make sense to leave some room for future-proofing. Also keep in mind that the more normalised your data is, the more convoluted your queries become - this might also be a factor to consider.